# Saving an image of off-screen views in PixelCopy

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-bitmap

I have a screen with a `ScrollView`. Then, I save the image of a view when I tap a button at the bottom of the scroll view. The problem I have is that I cannot save the upper part of the scrollView(which is off-screen) as an image. I am using `PixelCopy` with the following code:

```
fun takeScreenshot(view: View, activity: Activity){
    val loc = IntArray(2)
    view.getLocationInWindow(loc)
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    PixelCopy.request(
      activity.window,
      Rect(loc[0], loc[1], loc[0] + view.width, loc[1] + view.height),
      bitmap,
      {if(it = PixelCopy.SUCCESS) //convert to png and save},
      Handler(looper.getMainLooper())
    )
```

I want to achieve the same image like what

```
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
view.draw(canvas)
```

can achieve where I can just save a screenshot of the entire view even if the other part of the view is not visible on the screen. Is there a way to achieve this using `PixelCopy`?

Comment: same issue i have faced can any one help me this issue

Comment: I am stuck with 2 days but there is no solution I have found

Comment: @Alishan Are you fixed this issue?. can you post the answer if resolved