# Bitmap draw canvas: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want take screenshot of the HorizontalScrollview layout.

```
HorizontalScrollView z = view;      
        int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        view.draw(canvas);
```

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.onHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:632)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:639)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:73)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:131)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1648)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:275)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-9jGpkUE(CanvasDrawScope.kt:227)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-9jGpkUE(Unknown Source:37)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.715 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope$DefaultImpls.drawImage-9jGpkUE$default(DrawScope.kt:459)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter.onDraw(BitmapPainter.kt:55)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.draw.PainterModifier.draw(PainterModifier.kt:289)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedDrawNode.performDraw(ModifiedDrawNode.kt:102)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:255)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:254)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:128)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:254)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:54)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:234)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:239)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.716 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:814)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:105)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:98)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:255)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:254)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1776)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:123)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:254)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:54)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:234)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:239)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:814)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:105)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.717 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:68)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:68)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:68)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:814)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:672)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22357)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22227)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22225)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22357)
    2022-07-01 13:49:27.718 26174-26174 W/System.err:     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.draw(HorizontalScrollView.java:1743)
```

```
Targetsdkversion: 31

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    ext.compose_version = '1.0.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's Android version of the device/emulator throws this exception?

Comment: Above Android 8 face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using PixelCopy for Android version O and above.

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314397/java-lang-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bit)

```
fun captureView(view: View, window: Window, bitmapCallback: (Bitmap)->Unit) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Above Android O, use PixelCopy
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val location = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationInWindow(location)
        PixelCopy.request(window,
            Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + view.width, location[1] + view.height),
            bitmap,
            {
                if (it == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    bitmapCallback.invoke(bitmap)
                }
            },
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) )
    } else {
        val tBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(tBitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        canvas.setBitmap(null)
        bitmapCallback.invoke(tBitmap)
    }
}
```

I used this one to create a [screenshot library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot/blob/master/screenshot/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/screenshot/ScreenshotExtension.kt) for Compose

```
fun View.screenshot(
    bounds: Rect
): ImageResult {

    try {

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bounds.width.toInt(),
            bounds.height.toInt(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // Above Android O not using PixelCopy throws exception
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314397/java-lang-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bit
            PixelCopy.request(
                (this.context as Activity).window,
                bounds.toAndroidRect(),
                bitmap,
                {},
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            )
        } else {
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
                .apply {
                    translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
                }
            this.draw(canvas)
            canvas.setBitmap(null)
        }
        return ImageResult.Success(bitmap)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return ImageResult.Error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working full view of HorizontalScrollView screen, captured the image last scrolled position only.
What I expected is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084049/saving-an-image-of-off-screen-views-in-pixelcopy

Comment: It only captures the section of the View that is visible on screen.

Comment: If you want to capture whole view you need to have a logic that contains continues screenshoting based on scroll state and merging them. Since your question about crash relevant answers are in the link in java and kotlin.

Comment: Do you have any solution about horizontal screen view full screenshot.

Comment: At the moment there is none as far as i know. I asked the same question you do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894340/how-to-screenshot-selectively-or-scrollable-composable). What we get screenshot from is the View of the screen not the individual Composable. And you should ask your question for Views seperately as i did for Compose because what you ask now is different than original post.