# Convert a composable view into image in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable for example

```
Box(modifier){ ... }
```

I want to share this view as an image with other apps, that's why I have to convert this Box into an image that can be shared with other apps such as WhatsApp etc. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable or https://proandroiddev.com/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check out this link for how to build your own capturing system

[How to screenshot selectively or scrollable Composable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894340/how-to-screenshot-selectively-or-scrollable-composable)

You basically get view using

```
val view: View =  LocalView.current
```

then get position of your Composable using

```
var composableBounds by remember {
    mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null)
}
```

using onGloballyPositionedModifier

```
   Box(modifier = modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            composableBounds = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                it.boundsInWindow()
            } else {
                it.boundsInRoot()
            }
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
```

Then capturing image using

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    width,
    height,
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
)
```

`PixelCopy`, this is important, if you don't use this on Oreo and above you are likely to get [crash on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314397/java-lang-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
 PixelCopy.request(
            (this.context as Activity).window,
            bounds.toAndroidRect(),
            bitmap)
```

or

```
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        .apply {
            translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
        }
    this.draw(canvas)
    canvas.setBitmap(null)
    bitmapCallback.invoke(ImageResult.Success(bitmap))
```

i also created a library that takes screenshot or screenshots in specified interval.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot

Problem with mine and every other screen capture library out there is not being able to capture scrollable Composables by default.

Comment: so far the code  val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        .apply {
            translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
        }
    this.draw(canvas)
    canvas.setBitmap(null)
    bitmapCallback.invoke(ImageResult.Success(bitmap)) was giving compile time error. But I am trying to add your library, hope so it is going to solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: Your library seems to be working fine, and it is easy to use too. Thank you

Comment: Instead of the last canvas part which doesn't compile, I used applyCanvas on the bitmap : 
.applyCanvas {
      view.draw(this)
}

Comment: @Simon that Canvas is not `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas` it's `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas`

Comment: This works well, but when the view you want to capture is partially scrolled offscreen you only capture the part that is visible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `drawIntoCanvas` method and delegate to a `android.graphics.Picture` class.

```kotlin
val picture = remember { android.graphics.Picture() }
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawWithCache {
            // Example that shows how to redirect rendering to an Android Picture and then
            // draw the picture into the original destination
            val width = this.size.width.toInt()
            val height = this.size.height.toInt()
            onDrawWithContent {
                val pictureCanvas =
                    androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas(
                        picture.beginRecording(
                            width,
                            height
                        )
                    )
                draw(this, this.layoutDirection, pictureCanvas, this.size) {
                    this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
                }
                picture.endRecording()

                drawIntoCanvas { canvas -> canvas.nativeCanvas.drawPicture(picture) }
            }
        }
) {
    ScreenContentToCapture()
}
```

You can then save the `Picture` to disk using the following code:

```kotlin
private fun createBitmapFromPicture(picture: Picture): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        picture.width,
        picture.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE)
    canvas.drawPicture(picture)
    return bitmap
}

private suspend fun Bitmap.saveToDisk(context: Context): Uri {
    val file = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "screenshot-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
    )

    file.writeBitmap(this, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100)

    return scanFilePath(context, file.path) ?: throw Exception("File could not be saved")
}
```

The full snippet put together:

```kotlin
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.createChooser
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Picture
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.aspectRatio
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Share
import androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHost
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarResult
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawWithCache
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.draw
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.drawIntoCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.nativeCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.example.compose.snippets.R
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.rememberMultiplePermissionsState
import java.io.File
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCancellableCoroutine

/*
* Copyright 2022 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun BitmapFromComposableSnippet() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val picture = remember { Picture() }

    val writeStorageAccessState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // No permissions are needed on Android 10+ to add files in the shared storage
            emptyList()
        } else {
            listOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    )
    // This logic should live in your ViewModel - trigger a side effect to invoke URI sharing.
    // checks permissions granted, and then saves the bitmap from a Picture that is already capturing content
    // and shares it with the default share sheet.
    fun shareBitmapFromComposable() {
        if (writeStorageAccessState.allPermissionsGranted) {
            coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val bitmap = createBitmapFromPicture(picture)
                val uri = bitmap.saveToDisk(context)
                shareBitmap(context, uri)
            }
        } else if (writeStorageAccessState.shouldShowRationale) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                val result = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = "The storage permission is needed to save the image",
                    actionLabel = "Grant Access"
                )

                if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                    writeStorageAccessState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
                }
            }
        } else {
            writeStorageAccessState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                shareBitmapFromComposable()
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Share, "share")
            }
        }
    ) { padding ->
        // [START android_compose_draw_into_bitmap]
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawWithCache {
            // Example that shows how to redirect rendering to an Android Picture and then
            // draw the picture into the original destination
            val width = this.size.width.toInt()
            val height = this.size.height.toInt()
            onDrawWithContent {
                val pictureCanvas =
                    androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas(
                        picture.beginRecording(
                            width,
                            height
                        )
                    )
                draw(this, this.layoutDirection, pictureCanvas, this.size) {
                    this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
                }
                picture.endRecording()

                drawIntoCanvas { canvas -> canvas.nativeCanvas.drawPicture(picture) }
            }
        }
) {
    ScreenContentToCapture()
}
        // [END android_compose_draw_into_bitmap]
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ScreenContentToCapture() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                Brush.linearGradient(
                    listOf(
                        Color(0xFFF5D5C0),
                        Color(0xFFF8E8E3)
                    )
                )
            )
    ) {
        Image(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.sunset),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .padding(32.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Text(
            "Into the Ocean depths",
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )
    }
}

private fun createBitmapFromPicture(picture: Picture): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        picture.width,
        picture.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE)
    canvas.drawPicture(picture)
    return bitmap
}

private suspend fun Bitmap.saveToDisk(context: Context): Uri {
    val file = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "screenshot-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
    )

    file.writeBitmap(this, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100)

    return scanFilePath(context, file.path) ?: throw Exception("File could not be saved")
}

/**
 * We call [MediaScannerConnection] to index the newly created image inside MediaStore to be visible
 * for other apps, as well as returning its [MediaStore] Uri
 */
private suspend fun scanFilePath(context: Context, filePath: String): Uri? {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context,
            arrayOf(filePath),
            arrayOf("image/png")
        ) { _, scannedUri ->
            if (scannedUri == null) {
                continuation.cancel(Exception("File $filePath could not be scanned"))
            } else {
                continuation.resume(scannedUri)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
    outputStream().use { out ->
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, out)
        out.flush()
    }
}

private fun shareBitmap(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "image/png"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    startActivity(context, createChooser(intent, "Share your image"), null)
}
```

Comment: I can't see that DrawScope has such a "draw" method which you called in snippet line 128.

Comment: // requires at least 1.6.0-alpha01+ apparently :(

Answer (score -2):

You can get drawable using painter in jetpack compose, then use that Drawble to share..

```
    @Composable
fun photoItem(
    photoUrl: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit
): Drawable? {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .placeholder(drawable.placeholder)
            .data(photoUrl)
            .build()
    )
    Image(
        contentScale = contentScale,
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = modifier,
    )
    val state = painter.state as? AsyncImagePainter.State.Success
    return state?.result?.drawable
}
```

then cast the Drawable to BitmapDrawable

Answer (score -3):

```
Box(
modifier: BoxModifier(
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    color: Colors.red,
),
child: Image.network(
    'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
),
);
```

This code converts the Box into an image that can be shared with other apps. The BoxModifier class provides a way to modify the appearance of a box, and the Image class provides a way to display images.

Comment: No I don't want to show an online image. I want to convert a compose view into an image i-e bitmap or jpg etc