# Implement Draw, Undo, Redo, Erase and Save in canvas - Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-development, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am developing a drawing app with Jetpack Compose Canvas, I am able to draw on the canvas and undo/redo my hand-drawn strokes. I also need options to change the brush color and size. Finally, I want to save the image as both PNG and JPG.

I would be grateful for any code snippet, suggestions, references, or links.

Comment: [Jetpack Compose Drawing App](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Drawing-App) 
[Saving Composables as bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450838/convert-a-composable-view-into-image-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 0):

#### change the brush color and size

You can create a Paint with stroke color and size like:

```kotlin
strokePaint = Paint().also { paint ->
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    paint.style = STROKE
    paint.color = Color.RED
    paint.strokeWidth = 16
}
```

then draw your path with this Paint:

```kotlin
canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint)
```

#### save the image as both PNG and JPG

You can achieve it by :

1. create an Bitmap and Canvas with specific size:

```
val cacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val cacheCanvas = Canvas(cacheBitmap)
```

2. draw your paths to this canvas

```
cacheCanvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint)
```

3. save the Bitmap to file

```
val stream = FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png");
/* Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
cacheBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
stream.close();
```